# Are windows security settings on the file or on the location?

Tags: windows, windows-7

When I copy a file from one location to the other with the destination keep the original permissions or will it take the copied files permissions?

Answer (score 3):

> By default, an object inherits permissions from its parent object, either at the time of creation or when it is copied or moved to its parent folder. The only exception to this rule occurs when you move an object to a different folder on the same volume. In this case, the original permissions are retained.

Source: [Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310316)